# Rails one model multiple forms one page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, error-handling

I have a Rails Application which includes a User-Model.
The user can edit the attributes (address, name, password, locale).

To be RESTful, I've created a resource for the User-Model

```
#routes.rb
resources :users, only: [:edit, :update]
```

The page where the user can update his attributes (/users/:id/edit) contains multiple forms (one for the general information like address, one for the locale-setting and one to change his password).

each of this three forms looks something like this:

```
 = form_for(current_user, html: { class: 'fill-up' }) do |f|
    .padded
      = render 'shared/error_messages', object: current_user
      = f.label :locale
      .input
        = f.select(:locale, [['Deutsch', 'de'], ['English, 'en']])
    .form-actions
      = f.button 'Submit', class: 'button'
```

The problem is, if I render the edit-action to display the error-messages for the current_user-object, these error-messages will be shown on all three forms.

What is the Rails best-practice to split the model-attributes in different forms and display the error-messages only on one specific form, rather than on all.

Comment: So you're trying to show an error message in the form that used the attribute that caused the error?

Comment: Yes, up to now, the error-Messages are shown in every form, because each form gets the current_user-object. It would be great if one can specify only some attributes of the object to be handed over in the 'shared/error_messages'-Partial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one solution for this is, lets say you have 2 forms 
1) address
2) password

then in address edit form display only errors for address attribute for current_user like,

```
current_user.errors[:address] if current_user.errors.has_key?(:address )
```

and not

```
current_user.errors
```

similarly for password form you just display password errors

```
current_user.errors[:password] if current_user.errors.has_key?(:password )
```

this way you can avoid same errors in all forms.

Comment: Great! Worked like a charm! Thanks!